# TextBox Value Change if Other TextBoxes are filled in same windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 25 text boxes which record data of 24 hours in a day. And I have also a another text box named totalHours.text. My problem is that, if user enter data on only 6 or 8 or 20 or 25 hours data according to need then totalhours.text box filled by 6 or 8 or 20 or 25 hours. Means if user enter 10 hours data in 10 textboxes then totalhours.text automatically filled by 10. Means I need a code how can I count textboxes if they are filled and store the number of text boxes into another textbox.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have all your 24 textboxes in a panel named `container`

```
private void update()
{
  int count = 0;
  foreach(TextBox tbx in container.Controls)
  {
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbx.Text))
     count++;
  }

  CountertextBox.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Then, figure out a way to call `update()` method, for example each time you change a value of any of your other textboxes or whatever

Comment: how can i figure out i dont have any idea about that. tell me how can i use this method in key down event??

Comment: @AbdullahMujtaba use it as it is, just call it using the line code `update();`

Comment: it give me this error...An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DBHYDRO.exe 

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.